# unknown directive "passenger_app_group_name"

Tags: docker, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I am trying to tune my nginx + passenger to work with web sockets, I am trying to add the following to my `nginx.conf`

```
      passenger_app_group_name portal_action_cable;
      passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
```

but i am getting an error `unknown directive "passenger_app_group_name" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:69`

Below is the relevant part of my `nginx.conf`

```
    location /cable {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/cable;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
      proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      passenger_app_group_name portal_action_cable;
      passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
```

```
Nginx version is nginx/1.17.9
rails (5.2.3)
passenger (6.0.2)
```

I am using the docker image of nginx with above configuration file